# I tried installing chainercv but keeps failing, I used 3.7 and 3.9 but showing same error

Tags: python, chainercv

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for chainercv
Running setup.py clean for chainercv
Failed to build chainercv
ERROR: Could not build wheels for chainercv, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
(base.  could someone please help with chainercv installation, I tried in python 3.7 and 3.9 but all failed.

Comment: That is only a small part of the error message.  Please post the **whole** error message.

Answer (score -1):

You can install ChainerCV using pip by running the following commands:

```
pip install -U numpy
pip install chainercv
```

See [Installation Guide](https://chainercv.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html).

NB: This package hasn't been updated since 2019 and seems to be lacking certain details on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/chainercv/) such as supported python versions. However, if you encounter problems during installation, You may try downgrading to a lower version of Python3 and see if it works. Then run the above commands again.